# Pass a generic class in method parameter

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have a method which accepts two values and converts it into key-value pair of a map and returns it to the calling method. The key is always String but the value can be of any Class. I can't seem to convert the value into generic while accepting in method signature. Here's my code:

```
private Map<String, Class<T>> mapBuilder(String key, T value) {
        Map<String, Class <T>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(key, value);
        return map;
    }
```

Can someone tell what can be done instead?

Comment: Why not use `String key, Class<T> value` as the method params and call this method invoking `.class` on the params before passing them to the method?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to have a map with `Class` as a value? If so, you have firstly define a generic type parameter `<T>` either at the class level (`public class MyClass <T>  { ... }` or at the method level:

```
private <T> Map<String, Class<T>> mapBuilder(String key, T value) {
    Map<String, Class <T>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(key, (Class<T>) value.getClass());
    return map;
}
```

Note the following:

- As long as you want to add an instance of `Class<T>` to the map as a value, you have to get it from the `T` object.
- There is a problem with the type incompatibility as long as `getClass` returns `Class<?>`, so an explicit casting is needed (also in the snippet above).

Finally, I'd prefer a solution with the wildcard parameter:

```
private Map<String, Class<?>> mapBuilder(String key, T value) {
    Map<String, Class <?>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(key, value.getClass());
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Class` is too much. `T` already refers to the type:

```java
private <T> Map<String, T> mapBuilder(String key, T value) {
   Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put(key, value);
   return map;
}
```

`Class<T>` would refer to the class-object of `T`